# Getting the associated Output type of an Add implementation given LHS and RHS types

Tags: rust, traits, generic-programming, type-level-computation

In Rust, is there any way to, at the type level, summon an `Add` implementation by using the LHS (`Self`) and RHS types in order to use its `Output` type (in say, the return type of a generic function)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is, although it does look like a bit of black magic.

You need to combine 3 bits of syntax:

- the trait implementation of a type is accessible via `<Type as Trait>`
- specifying the `RHS` simply requires passing it as a parameter `Add<???>`
- and finally getting an associated type of a trait simply requires using `Trait::OutputType` (which may be ambiguous)

Combining the 3 together we get `<Self as Add<RhsType>>::Output`.

Comment: Thanks ! This was exactly what I was looking for. Specifying RHS as the generic parameter was the missing part of the puzzle in my case.